# SaaS, Multi-tenant (shared schema) - one table or two?

Tags: database-schema, saas, multi-tenant

I am creating a multi-tenant (shared-schema) database for a SaaS application.  The application will allow the subscribing company (the tenant) to collaborate with other companies (accounts – such as vendors, business partners, customers, etc.).  Users will be associated with both the tenant and the accounts.

**Here is my question**: from a design perspective, is it okay to put the tenants and accounts in one table?  I’m thinking “yes” because a company is a company regardless of whether they are a tenant or an account.  Further, I was thinking of deciphering a tenant with a field such as is_tenant (Boolean) and perhaps put tenant specific information in a separate table.  Here is a proposed schema:

- companies (company_id, is_tenant, name, address, etc.)
- users (user_id, name, email, username, password, etc.)
- company_users (company_id, user_id)
- tenant_information (company_id, billing_address, billing_state, etc.)
- tenant_accounts (tenant_id, account_id) – associates tenants with accounts [where tenant_id and account_id would be f_keys to the companies table]

I read through the MS article, [Multi-Tenant Data Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx) and, while helpful, it was short on providing an answer.

Any additional thoughts/comments/pitfalls regarding this schema would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would also agree with that... **if all the properties are same, then there is no need to create another table (data contract) for that**.

We are also using something of that sort. In a SAAS framework you always need to be careful in creating tables otherwise it will take a huge effort to refactor & migrate.

I have a question though! Cant see any "Company_Information" table which will have company specific info (which are not your tenants)

Comment: Hi Wali...thanks for the reply and vote of confidence.  It's good to know someone else is leaning towards this design.  And, you're right about the company_information table.  It's there, I just didn't include it in the example.  Any other thoughts out there?

Comment: To add to the same topic : 

We included some more type of "Companies" --> "Vendors", "Customers" and "Tenants", thus we ended up adding a enum instead of a bool field in **Company Table**. If you foresee something of that sort its better to have enum.

Comment: Wali...would you rather have a tenant_accounts table to associate a tenant with the accounts (vendors, customers, etc.) they do business with?  Or, could you just put a parent_id in the companies table create the relationship?  Is either design superior?

Comment: Having a tenant_accounts is more suggestible as that would separate all the tenant accounting led information in a table. 

Having a parent_id in companies table is NO NO for me, as that design is unnecessary complex. As a tenant all the account info shall be separated and should only have association with tenant table.

**My assumption is all the Customers and Vendors will be in Tenant table... if not then its a different proposition all together.**

Comment: Piet, what was the eventual design you went ahead with. Also share your experience with the design you went ahead with.